# Why cant Dns.GetHostAddresses get the IP Address for https://google.com?

Tags: c#, dns

I'm trying to get the Host Address's for "https://google.com" using the following code:

```
 var host = Dns.GetHostAddresses("https://google.com");
```

But I get an exception:

```
{"No such host is known"}
```

I was wondering, why I can't get the entries?

Comment: Just remove https. Host is google.com.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not give `https://` just give `google.com` as `https://` is not part of host name.

```
 var host = Dns.GetHostAddresses("google.com");
```

I found very good explanation of URL parts [here](https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/seo-glossary-url-definitions/) and excerpt is given as under.

```
http://video.google.co.uk:80/videoplay?docid=-7246927612831078230&hl=en#00h02m30s
```

Here are some of the components of the url:

> - The protocol is http. Other protocols include https, ftp, etc.
> - The host or hostname is video.google.co.uk.
> - The subdomain is video.
> - The domain name is google.co.uk.
> - The top-level domain or TLD is uk. The uk domain is also referred to as a country-code top-level domain or ccTLD. For google.com, the TLD
>     would be com.
> - The second-level domain (SLD) is co.uk.
> - The port is 80, which is the default port for web servers. Other ports are possible; a web server can listen on port 8000, for example.
>     When the port is 80, most people leave out the port.
> - The path is /videoplay. Path typically refers to a file or location on the web server, e.g. /directory/file.html
> - This URL has parameters. The name of one parameter is docid and the value of that parameter is -7246927612831078230. URLs can have lots
>     parameters. Parameters start with a question mark (?) and are
>     separated with an ampersand (&). See the “#00h02m30s”? That’s called a
>     fragment or a named anchor. The Googlers I’ve talked to are split
>     right down the middle on which way to refer it. Disputes on what to
>     call it can be settled with arm wrestling, dance-offs, or drinking
>     contests.  Typically the fragment is used to refer to an internal
>     section within a web document. In this case, the named anchor means
>     “skip to 2 minutes and 30 seconds into the video.” I think right now
>     Google standardizes urls by removing any fragments from the url.

Answer (score 1):

`var host = Dns.GetHostAddresses("google.com")[0];`

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the **https://**. It should be like this:

```
var host = Dns.GetHostAddresses("google.com");
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use to get first IP address from the list

```
  var address = Dns.GetHostAddresses("www.test.com")[0];
```